# I was trying to print the value of count in my data variable in laravel, the following is the value of the variable

Tags: php, arrays

print_r($data) gives the below value, I am not sure about how to get the count value from the below

```
 Array ( [result] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [_id] => [count] => 6 ) ) [ok] => 1 )
```

I want to get 6 as output

Comment: $data['result'][0]['count']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may explictly access the array using its variable name then the keys

For example:

```
$data['result'][0]['count']
```